# jQuery ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tab

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь сделать табы на аяксе. Все работает, но есть пару вопросов.
Вот разметка

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="/post/{{ $post->slug }}" data-ajax-tab>Рекомендуемые</a></li>
    <li><a href="/post/{{ $post->slug }}/most-viewed" data-ajax-tab>Самые просматриваемые</a></li>
    <li><a href="/post/{{ $post->slug }}/popular" data-ajax-tab>Популярные<span>(0)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Вот сам скрипт

```
var ajaxLoader = $('[data-loader]');
$('[data-ajax-tab]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    var url = link.attr('href');
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    link.parent().addClass('active');
    var contentArea = $('[data-post-content]');
    contentArea.empty();
    ajaxLoader.show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.get({
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(template)
            {
                contentArea.append(template);
                ajaxLoader.hide()
            },
            error: function(error)
            {

            }
        })
    }, 2000);
});
```

Сейчас, если перейти по адресу `site.name/post/bla-bla/popular`, то отдается шаблон, который при нажатии на таб `популярные` отдается. А как сделать, что бы загрузилась страница, и автоматически таб `популярные` стал активен?

И второй вопрос, почему query string не изменяется? Я ведь методом гет получаю. Таб активируется, а адрес остается без изменений.

Comment: А про вторую часть вопроса можно подробнее написать?

Comment: @Станислав ну допустим я нахожусь на странице `site.name/post/perviy-probniy-post`. Затем, под постом я жму на таб `популярные`. Этот таб имеет адрес вида `site.name/post/perviy-probniy-post/popular`, таб активируется, популярные посты появляются. Но адрес старници остается `site.name/post/perviy-probniy-post`, почему не ``site.name/post/perviy-probniy-post/popular`? Я ведь $.get({}) использую. Он ведт должен по данному адресу перейти?

Comment: то есть в смысле в адресной строке браузера что ли адрес не меняется?

Comment: Да. Вот пример что я хочу сделать. Если перейти по по этому адресу http://hotline.ua/computer-noutbuki-netbuki/acer-spin-sp714-51-m0bk-nxgkpeu002/prices/ , то открывается страница, и таб с ценами становится активным и подгружает шаблон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на первую часть вопроса - да просто убрать класс active у предыдущего элемента и сделать его активным у нужного. Вы уже пытаетесь это сделать:

```
$('li.active').removeClass('active');
link.parent().addClass('active');
```

Разве не работает?

На вторую часть вопроса смогу дать ответ позже, как конкретизируете его. Впрочем, если я верно вас понял, то функция `$.get()` и не должна менять адресную строку браузера, так как единственная ее функция - это взять посредством ajax-запроса какой-либо контент. По сути, это обертка для `$.ajax()`, которая сделана ради понятности кода.

Так что, отвечая на вторую часть вашего запроса, вам нужно менять адресную строку самому. Это делается через объект `window`, а точнее через `window.history`. Есть как готовые библиотеки и функции для работы с ним, так и возможность нативно сделать то, что вы хотите. Заметьте, что только при работе с этим объектом пользователь у вас сможет получать ожидаемую работу с историей браузера, когда перемещение по истории будет работать так, как оно и должна работать при динамическом изменении контента.

Comment: Вы не поняли. В первой части вопроса проблема в не в активном табе. Пример привел в комментарии выше

Comment: А, понял вас. Сек

Comment: @Alex_01 обновил ответ.